# How does noexcept in lambda work in vs2012?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, lambda, noexcept

While trying to do the compile example from:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=vs-2019#exception-specification

using *Visual studio 2012*

```
[]() noexcept { throw 5; }();
```

I have got the following error:

> expected a '{' introducing a lambda body

Comment: It doesn't work. vs2012 is old and the compiler that shifts with it doesn't implement C++11 fully. I recommends upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) has been introduced in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), but the [MSVS2015 onwards](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c111417-features-in-vs-2015-rtm/) only(unfortunately) one can use this feature. Meaning, you need to upgrade to MSVS2015 and set the compiler flag C++11 or C++14 to compile this code.